# Remove all duplicates BELOW based on "if" condition in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

can someone help me figure out how to get Excel to do the following:

IF (B2 = "YES") remove all duplicates of B2 below it

Column A has (non-unique) phone numbers and Column B has "outcomes" (YES, MAYBE, and a handful of others) and I want Excel to remove all rows with a certain phone number after it first "got" the value "YES" in B, but keep all of the duplicates above it.

SAMPLE DATA:

```
    10      NO          
    20      NO ANSWER   
    10      YES         
    30      NO ANSWER   
    10      YES         
    10      NO ANSWER   
    20      YES         
    10      YES         
    40      NO                    
    20      YES          
    20      NO ANSWER
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
    10      NO          
    20      NO ANSWER   
    10      YES         
    30      NO ANSWER            
    20      YES                 
    40      NO
```

I've tried to make a few helper columns with IF statements to no success.

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1532084/edit) to provide sample data and expected outcome

Comment: Hi, I've edited it now - sorry I didn't do this initially!

Answer (score 0):

You can create helper column with formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1=$A$1:A1)*("yes"=$B$1:B1))>1
```

and then filter and delete everything that is `TRUE`

[image]